# how to print intermediate results of quicksort highlighting its pivot element correctly

Tags: c

This is a homework question. My code does not highlight the pivot element of each iteration of Quick-sort correctly.

I have read pre-answered questions too, but they don't answer my query.
Here is my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>

FILE *ptr1, *ptr2;

void printarray(int a[], int n, int p )
{
 int i;
 for (i=0;i<=n; i++)
  {//if (a[i] == a[p])
   if (i == p)
    {
    printf("<%d> ", a[p]);
    i++;
    }
 printf("%d ", a[i]);

 }
}

void swap (int a[], int left, int right)
{
 int temp;
 temp=a[left];
 a[left]=a[right];
 a[right]=temp;
}

int partition (int arr[], int l, int h)
{
    int x = arr[h];
    int temp,j;
    int i = (l - 1);

    for (j = l; j <= h- 1; j++)
    {
        if (arr[j] <= x)
        {
            i++;
            swap (arr,i,j);
        }
    }
    temp = i+1;
    swap (arr,temp,h);
    return (temp);
}

/* A[] --> Array to be sorted, l  --> Starting index, h  --> Ending index */
void quickSort(int A[], int l, int h)
{
    if (l < h)
    {       
        int p = partition(A, l, h); /* Partitioning index */

    printarray(A,h,p);
    printf("\n");

    quickSort(A, l, p - 1); 
    quickSort(A, p + 1, h);
    //printarray(A,h,p);
    //printf("\n");

    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a[20];                  // array to store values of input file
    int i= 0,n = 0;

     ptr1 =fopen(argv[1],"r");

    while(!feof(ptr1))
    {
     fscanf(ptr1,"%d",&a[n]);
    // printf("%d ",a[n]);
     n++;
    }
    //sum = a[--i];
   // printf("\n %d ",sum);
    fclose(ptr1);

    n = n-2;
//printf("%d ",a[n]);
    ptr2 = fopen(argv[2],"w");

       quickSort(a,0,n+1);
for (i=0; i<n+1; i++)
        { fprintf( ptr2,"%d ",a[i]); 
         printf( "%d ",a[i]);

    }printf("\n"); 
     fclose(ptr2);

    return 0}
```

note  - ignore command line arguments and file handling calls..

Comment: Aside: `while(!feof(ptr1)) ...` leaves the last `a[n]` uninitialized.  Wrong use of `foef()`.  Instead check return value from `fscanf()`.

Comment: @chux Why does it leave it uninitialized?

Comment: But its printing the output correct, I am concerned about intermediate results and highlighting of pivot.

Comment: How does code know it _is_ initialized?  Code does not check the result of `fscanf()`.  Hint: `feof()` is too late.  "But its printing the output correct" --> with mysterious `n = n-2;` and `i<n+1;`, code does not print the last result of `fscanf(ptr1,"%d",&a[n]);`, so maybe code is thinking it reads 20 `int`, but in fact is attempting to read 21 `int`s then stepping on memory.

Comment: Instead of `while(!feof(ptr1)) { fscanf(ptr1,"%d",&a[n]); n++; ... n - n-2`... quickSort(a,0,n+1);, use `while((n<20) && (1 == fscanf(ptr1,"%d",&a[n])) n++; ... quickSort(a,0,n);`.. This all may not be _the_ issue, but with potential UB up front, the rest of code behavior is guess work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code should pass `l` to the `printarray` function in addition to `h` and `p`, so that you only print the portion of the array that's being partitioned, instead of printing from the beginning of the array every time.

Inside of the `printarray` function, the logic should look something like this

```
for ( i = l; i <= h; i++ )
{
    if ( i == p )
        print with <%d>
    else
        print normally
}
```

That way, the code in the loop isn't messing around with the index, and only prints once per loop.  With the code in the question, it's possible to print beyond the end of the array since you increment `i` inside the loop, and then call `printf` again without checking whether `i` is still `<= n`.

Comment: I tried what u suggested, but the result is not the desired output..
This is the output according to your suggestion if I enter 45 43 41 39 37 35 33 as input.

45  43  41  39  37  35  33  <134520820>  3 
 <33>  43  41  39  37  35  45 
 43  41  39  37  35  <45>  134520820 
 <35>  41  39  37  43 
 41  39  37  <43>  45 
 <37>  39  41 
 39  <41>  43